# Publish WinUI 3 app in Microsoft Store (Windows 11)

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2022, winui-3, windows-11, winui

I started developing a WinUI 3 application from scratch to Windows 11 to publish to the Microsoft Store but i can't find any option in Visual Studio to create the package and upload. I developed several UWP applications for Windows 10 and never had any problems. In WinUI 3 is different? Can someone help me? please

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Don't you have a `Publish` option available in Visual Studio if you right-click on the packaging project? Or what project template did you use?

Comment: I edit the post. After reinstall Visual Studio 2022, now I have that option. What I need to do now? Publish? In UWP it was more simple.

Comment: In the packaging project, you should have the `Publish->Create App Packages...` and `Publish->Associate App with the Store...` options. Or how did you publish your UWP app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem too. On creating your project you have to choose the template that says "Blank App, Packaged with Windows Application Packaging Project (WinUI 3 in Desktop)". Then you should see the store options again.

I first tried  "Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)", did not seem to give me the option even though it seems to mention the Microsoft store in the description.

Edit:
The other thing I didn't mention is you have to do the publish from the package project not from the main one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the "Package and Publish" option further down the pop-up[image]